# Recibo NaN cuando trato de convertir un valor de Fahrenheit a Celsius

Tags: javascript, html

Mi pregunta es sobre mostrar en un evento input la conversión de grados Fahrenheit a Celsius pero no sé qué tengo en mi código que no funciona:

```js
var inputFahrenheit = document.getElementById('inputFahrenheit');
inputFahrenheit.addEventListener('input', function
FahrenheitToCelcius(fahrenheit) {
  var celcius = ((fahrenheit - 32) / 1.8);
  document.getElementById('returnFahrenheit').value = celcius;
});
```

```html
<div class="contenedor" id="contenedor">
  <div class="formulario" id="formulario">
    <h2>Fahrenheit to Celcius</h2>
    <input type="text" class="input" id="inputFahrenheit" placeholder="Input degrees Fahrenheit">
    <input type="text" class="input" id="returnFahrenheit" placeholder="Result" readonly>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Por cierto, es [Celsius, con S](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grado_Celsius)

Answer (score 4):

Sumar un objeto a un número en JS devuelve [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/NaN) (Not a Number).

En tu caso particular estas utilizando el argumento `fahrenheit` pensando que este tiene el valor del input. En realidad lo que tiene, es un objeto. Especificamente, el evento al que tu event listener está asignado. El objeto evento posee muchas propiedades, entre ellas el valor del elemento capturado por el listener.

Es por eso, que el parámetro del evento se denomina `e` o `event` (que deriva del idioma inglés).

`target` es el elemento en si, y `value` es el valor asignado al elemento (qué es lo que estás buscando).

Como el input transforma todo a una cadena de texto (String), podemos hacer uso de [`ParseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseFloat) para convertirlo a un número decimal para luego realizar el cálculo aritmético.

Ademas, puedes darle al input el atributo `type="number"` para limitar el ingreso solamente a números.

Finalmente, puedes usar un [condicional ternario](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Conditional_Operator) para actualizar los datos a nada y evitar que te muestre `NaN` cuando el input está vacío.

```js
// capturar el input
const inputFahrenheit = document.getElementById('inputFahrenheit');
// agregar el event listener
inputFahrenheit.addEventListener('input', fahrenheitToCelsius)


function fahrenheitToCelsius(event) {
  // interceptamos el valor del input element asociado al listener
  const celsius = ((parseFloat(event.target.value) - 32) / 1.8);
  // Mostramos el resultado
  document.getElementById('returnFahrenheit').value = celsius ? celsius.toFixed(2): '' ;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor" id="contenedor">
  <div class="formulario" id="formulario">
    <h2>Fahrenheit a Celsius</h2>
    <input type="number" class="input" id="inputFahrenheit" placeholder="Grados Fahrenheit">
    <input type="text" class="input" id="returnFahrenheit" placeholder="Resultado" readonly>
  </div>
</div>
```

Nota: [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/toFixed) permite mostrar la cantidad de decimales que quieras.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que pasa es que el evento [.`addEventListener()` de tipo input](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) te devuelve un objeto. Este objeto tiene varias llaves, entre ellas la llave `"data"`, esta solo toma el último valor ingresado por teclado y es de tipo string.

A la hora de  hacer un operación aritmética, que involucre un elemento tipo string, vas a obtener como resultado `NaN`. Como digo, puedes acceder a la llave `"data"`, pero esta no va a almacenar todo el número ingresado en el input, si no solo el último dígito.

```
var inputFahrenheit = document.getElementById('inputFahrenheit');
string = "";

inputFahrenheit.addEventListener('input', function(fahrenheit) {
    let celcius = (parseFloat(fahrenheit.data) - 32) / 1.8;
    document.getElementById('returnFahrenheit').value = celcius;
});
```

Esto no es óptimo, lo más adecuado es dejar de interactuar con el objeto que retorna el evento. En vez de esto, usar la propiedad `value` del elemento.

```js
let inputFahrenheit = document.getElementById('inputFahrenheit');

inputFahrenheit.addEventListener("input", () => {
  let inputCelcius = document.getElementById("returnFahrenheit");

  inputCelcius.value = (parseFloat(inputFahrenheit.value) - 32) / 1.8;
});
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="contenedor" id="contenedor">         
    <div class="formulario" id="formulario">
      <h2>Fahrenheit to Celcius</h2>
      <input type="text" class="input" id="inputFahrenheit" placeholder="Input degrees Fahrenheit">
      <input type="text" class="input" id="returnFahrenheit" placeholder="Result" readonly>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

***Nota:** Aquí se usa [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseFloat) para convertir el string que es el valor de un input a número de punto decimal*

Saludos.